# Insert space in words for \seqsplit

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,seqsplit}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c |c |c |X |X |X |}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 
         \seqsplit{Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3l} & 
         \seqsplit{Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3} & 
         \seqsplit{Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3} \\
         \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{tes}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Outcome:
[image]

The words suppose to be

```
Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3
```

But it came out to be

```
Testing1testing2Testing3
```

Comment: as commented on your last question seqsplit was only suggested as you provided a random string of letters, it is not suitable for _words_ you never split at a random place, split at the word space or use tex's hyphenation,

Answer (score 2):

You can first replace spaces with “implicit spaces” and then map the token list adding `\hspace{0pt}` after each item.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\spliteverywhere}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__spliteverywhere_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__spliteverywhere_tl { ~ } { \c_space_tl }
  \tl_map_function:NN \l__spliteverywhere_tl \__spliteverywhere:n
 }
\tl_new:N \l__spliteverywhere_tl
\cs_new:Nn \__spliteverywhere:n { #1 \hspace{0pt} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c |c |c |X |X |X |}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 
         \spliteverywhere{Testing 1 testingtesting 2 Testing 3l} & 
         \spliteverywhere{Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3} & 
         \spliteverywhere{Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3} \\
         \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{test}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`seqsplit` is for breaking sequences of letters from computer codes etc, for natural language text it is better to use TeX's normal line breaking:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c |c |c |X |X |X |}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 
         Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3l & 
         Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3 & 
         Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3 \\
         \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{tes}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Does it works with `\usepackage{multirow}` to combine 2 row into 1?